# Please let's solve problems in a region-independent way

Tags: discussion

I often see solutions which only work in English environments. However, according to my experience of 20+ years, this approach produces a lot of problems.

As an example, see this: [Find Mondays between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30777605/2504785)

There are two answers which which will work only in English environments!

Can we please have some guidelines to ensure that problems are always solved in a region-independent way?

Comment: If you feel existing answers don't deal with these edge cases, comment or (if drastic enough) submit your own answer that does. I agree these problems exist -- but expecting every solution to every question to take it into account is unrealistic and (for a lot of questions) simply unnecessary for the point at hand.

Comment: To “**ensure** that problems are **always** solved in a region-independent way” (my emphasis) is overkill. What is reasonable is to try to make questioners and answerers more aware of this issue, yet I fear that even that is hard to achieve: it would be worth mentioning this aspect in the help pages about asking and answering, but that would probably not be very effective. I am sorry to see this question voted down so far; I’ve voted back up.

Comment: The Old New Thing: [How do you convince developers to pay their "taxes"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/08/22/454487.aspx)

Answer (score 19):

This is not a problem for Stack Exchange to solve by trying to come up with more rules and guidelines.  This is a problem for the community to solve.

The tooltip for the downvote button on an answer explicitly says "This answer is not useful".  So if it solves a problem in a way that is not useful to you, then it is by definition "not useful" and you should have zero problems downvoting it.

In addition to choosing to vote or not vote, you can simply leave a comment that says:

> While this answer may solve the problem for `x` calendar system, it is going to fail (or be incorrect) in other cultures because of `y`.

Then leave an answer of your own (if you have an answer) on how to solve the problem in a more generic method or for another culture that is not covered in the existing answers.

However, one thing to keep in mind before you cast that vote, is keep in mind what the original question was asking.  If the original question asked about a **specific** culture (or a general idea of the culture involved can be extrapolated from the content of the question), it is probably a bit unfair to expect someone to write an answer to cover every possibility.  Doesn't stop you from commenting, if nothing more than to help future users see the limitations of the answer.

Comment: This is obviously the right thing to do in the circumstances, but it does not tackle two issue: wasted effort and unspotted bugs. Date manipulations in particular may only fail in special cases, which may not be covered by the test plan (which we hope exists).

Answer (score 4):

A proper guideline is that users that ask questions at an American web site that uses English as the required language should explicitly state in their question that they have localization sensitive requirements.

Another one is that SO users fill out their profile and mention their location. I often look at it when localization plays a role in a question but it is very often missing.  No real idea why this needs to be a secret.  Hard to enforce.  Not a oversight this OP made, those date strings are not Indian and strongly suggest he's working on an outsourced project.

Comment: Developers from the whole world use english as a communication language, but that does for sure not mean that they are in the USA!

Comment: Ah, thanks, I did not know that.

Comment: I would suggest the reverse guideline: I would *assume* that any question would be looking for answers that would help everyone, not just users who *only* need to run their application in a single language, or using servers in a particular locale. In the example given by Giosco, the idea of "Mondays between particular dates" isn't inherently localization-sensitive (although it probably assumes a Gregorian calendar) but at least one of the *answers* was unnecessarily sensitive to the locale of the server it was running on.

Comment: Covered by the second paragraph.

Comment: If I'm searching for the answer to a problem (maybe asked and answered years ago), I don't want to have to check the user profile of the person who asked originally the question - the question should stand alone, containing all the relevant information in it.

Comment: Covered by the first paragraph.

Comment: An Indian working on an outsourced project? Come now, that's unthinkable.

Comment: @JonSkeet In the answers to the monday problem, I found two issues: a) `DATENAME(dw, dat)` delivers the text "Monday" only in english environments. b) Monday is the 2nd(!) day of the week in the USA, but the 1st (!) day of the week in Europe! Therefore, `DATEPART(dw, dat)` delivers either 1 or 2 for monday. So, you need to use `SET DATEFIRST x` also.

Comment: The OP’s profile does (at this moment) show that he is located in India works for a company in Cochin.

Comment: It is all very well to say _“They … inevitably discover this … when they get answers that don't help …”_; this overlooks two problems: wasted effort and unspotted bugs. Date manipulations in particular may only fail in special cases, perhaps missed by the test plan.

Comment: When is the first version of a question ever adequate?  Good Q+A that has lasting value almost always has an edited question.

Comment: I have cancelled my downvote, which was a reaction to “an American web site that uses English”, which I found (and find) a bit parochial. But even for a pretty international site, which in terms of its users this is, and independent of the language of the site, it is fair to say that askers need to state constraints explicitly. So maybe I will even vote up. _But_, I think this requirement, too often disregarded, is especially easy to overlook in the case of locale, which is why my answer proposes amending the help pages to remind askers and answerers to take _all_ constraints into account.

Comment: I'm Dutch, we're only ever parochial about soccer and skating.  And like the old joke: Q: what do you call somebody that speaks multiple languages? A: a polyglot.  Q: speaks two languages? A: bi-lingual.  Q: speaks one language? A: an American.

Comment: @HansPassant: Many of us British are no better, but at least others make the effort. I found the hardest thing about learning Dutch was getting people not to switch to English! I was (favourably) impressed by the amount of space in the Haarlem paper dedicated to the Elfstedentocht and the controversy about Brand Corstius and his prize.

Answer (score 4):

If it's your own question, why don't you make it clear what date format/etc you are using?

This isn't up to the answerer to make it clear what should and should be multi-regional, but the asker. If it's not your question, And as such the answers do not solve your issues, then **Ask a new question** (after ensuring such question hasn't been asked before).

You can't always expect answerers who have answered for 'x' region to also know a 'solution' to 'y' region.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest we should try to raise awareness of this issue, but as part of a more generally applicable tweak to the help pages. I fear this will have less effect than one would hope for, but I think it would still do some good to make certain points there.

In [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), just after the section “Introduce the problem before you post any code”, we could use a new section: “Say exactly what you need” (which people so often do not), with tips like:

- What input do you have?
- What result do you want?
- Are there any performance or size constraints?
- Are there any constraints on region/locale, the OS, DBMS, compiler, …?
- Is there a full statement of the problem elsewhere to quote and/or link?

In [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), in the section “Answer the question”, we could add a new sentence or paragraph to remind people to check all the questioner’s constraints (or point out which are no/partly satisfied), and to think whether there may be constraints the questioner has overlooked, and maybe, as Hans Passant’s answer suggests, to check their location.